# How to calculate month by month change in value per user in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I was looking for similar topics, but I found only change by month. My problem is that I would like to have a month change in value e.g. UPL but per user like in the below example.

| user_id | month | UPL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 100 |
| 1 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00 | 200 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 100 |
| 2 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00 | 50 |
| 1 | 2022-03-01 00:00:00 | 150 |

And to have additional column named "UPL change month by month":

| user_id | month | UPL | UPL_change_by_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 100 | 0 |
| 1 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00 | 200 | 100 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 100 | 0 |
| 2 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00 | 50 | -50 |
| 1 | 2022-03-01 00:00:00 | 150 | -50 |

Is it possible using aggfunc or shift function using Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `groupby_diff`:

```
df['UPL_change_by_month'] = df.sort_values('month').groupby('user_id')['UPL'].diff().fillna(0)
print(df)

# Output
   user_id      month  UPL  UPL_change_by_month
0        1 2022-01-01  100                  0.0
1        1 2022-02-01  200                100.0
2        2 2022-01-01  100                  0.0
3        2 2022-02-01   50                -50.0
4        1 2022-03-01  150                -50.0
```

Comment: Thank you! Do I have to sort values by month first?

Comment: Yes you have to sort by `month` first: `df.sort_values('month').groupby('user_id')['UPL'].diff().fillna(0)`